# Questions about win7 slow domain logon

Tags: windows

Recently, users reports slow logon in some win7 computers. I enabled verbose and found that it stuck on user profile servicing for around 50 seconds. I found that the roaming profile only 10MB in size. I use another domain user account with another roaming profile and it logon fast. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use [xperf to troubleshoot slow logons](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/10128.tools-for-troubleshooting-slow-boots-and-slow-logons-sbsl.aspx#Using_XPERF_to_capture_slow_logons).

1. install the [WPT](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4847.install-the-windows-performance-toolkit-wpt.aspx)
2. logon to an admin account
3. open a cmd.exe and run this command:

> xperf -on base+latency+dispatcher+NetworkTrace+Registry+FileIO
>   -stackWalk CSwitch+ReadyThread+ThreadCreate+Profile -BufferSize 1024 -start UserTrace -on "Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Core+Microsoft-Windows-Wininit+Microsoft-Windows-Folder Redirection+Microsoft-Windows-User Profiles
>   Service+Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy+Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon+Microsoft-Windows-Security-Kerberos+Microsoft-Windows-User
>   Profiles
>   General+e5ba83f6-07d0-46b1-8bc7-7e669a1d31dc+63b530f8-29c9-4880-a5b4-b8179096e7b8+2f07e2ee-15db-40f1-90ef-9d7ba282188a"
>   -BufferSize 1024 -MinBuffers 64 -MaxBuffers 128 -MaxFile 1024

4. Press CTRL+ALT+DEL and then Switch User.
5. Logon with the user account experiencing the slow user logon to reproduce the issue.
6. in the slow account, open a elevated/admin command prompt and run this:

> xperf -stop -stop UserTrace -d merged.etl

7. open the `merged.etl` in [WPA.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh448170.aspx), look in the Generic Events for events with matching Start/Stop Opcodes and look which Event has a long duration.

If you need help, compress the `merged.etl` as 7z/RAR (to reduce the size) and share it (oneDrive, dropbox, google drive).

Comment: have you tried this? Do you need help?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am too busy these day to try this. I will handle it when available

Comment: ok, do this. if you need help, share the compressed file

Comment: any update? have you captured the trace?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I have left the organization. and do not have a chance to try it anymore. Thanks a lot for your passion